# How to add action for UITableView index event - for each alphabet letter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, action

I have alphabet strip (index), like in Apple's Contacts app, showing in a `UITableView` but now I want to add an action for each and every letter when I touch them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) protocol.

You'll easily know which letter was touched.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the fact that the tableView is a scrollView and that your `<UITableViewDelegate>` will also conform to `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` and use the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(![scrollView isDragging] && ![scrollView isDecelerating]) {
        NSLog(@"User scrolled using tableView index");
    }
}
```

Best,